# karate.env is not working as expected from command line in karate

Tags: maven, karate

Below is my config.js

```
function fn() {
  var env = karate.env; // get java system property 'karate.env'
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', karate.env);
  if (!env) {
    env = 'dev'; // a custom 'intelligent' default
  }
  var config = { // base config JSON
    tokenId: 'glpat-_JhsWtKDxTDdj8y7MSrT',
    incorrectToken: 'glpat-yTewu9RxV97K6Uj385v',
    baseUrl: 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4',
    sampleProjectId: '39946432'
  };
  if (env == 'ST') {
    // over-ride only those that need to be
    config.baseUrl = 'https://st-host/v1/auth';
  } else if (env == 'e2e') {
    config.baseUrl = 'https://et-host/v1/auth';
  }
  // don't waste time waiting for a connection or if servers don't respond within 5 seconds
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
  karate.configure('ssl', true);
  return config;
}
```

**Below code works fine:**

If I modified my Runner class with below code -

```
@BeforeClass
public static void before() {
    System.setProperty("karate.env", "e2e");
}
```

and Run -

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestRunnerE2E
```

Then I get in karate.log as -

```
09:13:02.200 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: e2e
```

**Below set up doesn't work fine:**
But I don't want keep different runner files for different environments.
So I tried to run below commands -

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=e2e"
mvn test -Denv=e2e
```

But in both cases environment is not set correctly -

```
09:20:10.799 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: local
```

Not sure what am I missing here? It works fine by setting up system.setProperty but not directly from commandline.

**maven details:**

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T17:06:16+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_342, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc., runtime: C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Best Regards,

Abhi

Comment: the only way to let others help you is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - else I suggest you figure this out on your own, and contribute your findings back to the community here

Comment: @PeterThomas : I edited my question, as you suggested.

Comment: hope someone else can help. this requires some research into maven etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figure out the solution or not. You can pass the *karate.env* as a standalone argument in your *mvn* command. Here is an example.

```
mvn test clean -Dkarate.env=testValFromCmd
```